# change ace editor line numbering to relative to cursor

Tags: ace-editor, line-numbers

Is it possible to change the line numbering of Ace Editor to show lines relative to current cursor position, such as in the following gif?  Of course it does not need to be as pretty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is relativeLineNumbers option in the editor, which looks almost that pretty

```
editor.setOption("relativeLineNumbers", true)
```